# how can i extract month and date and year from data column in R

Tags: r, database

I had a column with date datatype. in my column the dates are in 4/1/2007 format. now I want to extract month value from that column and date value from that column in different column in R. my date are from 01/01/2012 to 01/01/ 2015 plz help me.

Comment: `4/1/2007 format` ? Is that 4th of January, or 1st of April?

Answer (score 3):

If your variable is date type (as you say in the post) simply use following to extract month:

```
month_var = format(df$datecolumn, "%m") # this will give output like "09"
month_var = format(df$datecolumn, "%b") # this will give output like "Sep"
month_var = format(df$datecolumn, "%B") # this will give output like "September"
```

If your date variable in not in date format, then you will have to convert them into date format.

```
df$datecolumn<- as.Date(x, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: Let me know if you still have questions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your initial data is `character` and not `POSIX`.

```
df <- data.frame(d = c("4/1/2007", "01/01/2012", "02/01/2015"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
#            d
# 1   4/1/2007
# 2 01/01/2012
# 3 02/01/2015
```

These are not yet "dates", just strings.

```
df$d2 = as.POSIXct(df$d, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
df
#            d         d2
# 1   4/1/2007 2007-04-01
# 2 01/01/2012 2012-01-01
# 3 02/01/2015 2015-02-01
```

Now they proper dates (in the R fashion). These two lines extract just a single component from each "date"; see [`?strptime`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) for details on all available formats.

```
df$dY = format(df$d2, "%Y")
df$dm = format(df$d2, "%m")
df
#            d         d2   dY dm
# 1   4/1/2007 2007-04-01 2007 04
# 2 01/01/2012 2012-01-01 2012 01
# 3 02/01/2015 2015-02-01 2015 02
```

An alternative method would be to extract the substrings from each string, but now you're getting into regex-pain; for that, I'd suggest sticking with somebody else's regex lessons-learned, and translate through `POSIXct` (or even `POSIXlt` if you want).